# Max contiguous subarray sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So, i just had an online programming assessment where i was given 2 problems one of which was this contiguous subarray sum provided 2 Complex coding questions + 8 mcqs and was to be completed in 1 hr.

Here i would be discussing one of the above mentioned max contiguous sum of subarray. Usually the tough part i find was handling negative numbers and contiguously. What i did was i first applied a `Collection.sort(arr)` to the given array and i again sorted the negative values by their absolute value like `for i.. arr.get(i)! =abs(arr.get(i)) for j.. if arr.get(i)>arr.get(j) then swap so final array is -1, -2, 3,4,5` for example for given random numbers array and i mantain a max after each i and all j iterations per that I have `if max<sum(i.e. sum+arr.get(allj)+arr(particular i) then max=sum`. So this was giving me the max sum but I got 4 cases passed out of 14 and i thought the reason being sorted array wouldnt be always contiguous so any suggestions so as to how would i inculcate such contiguous logic within this to make it work for all cases.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, nor what your current code is.  Not sure why you'd need to sort negative numbers again; if you sort an array numerically it'll already be in numeric order.

Comment: I had to reorder negative numbers because it wasnt making the other sequence as contiguous usually the higher the no the lower its value in case of negative numbers so when sort is applied negative numbers align as -2, -1,.. so contiguous was the part which was causing the problem with the positive ones

Comment: But if you re-order the array how would you then find the "contiguous" parts?

Comment: Umm.. I guess sorting somewhat does make it contiguous  just that in case the numbers have different sum in sorted order then we have to break

Comment: It certainly makes the entire array contiguous, but then the "largest contiguous subarray" is the entire array, which somewhat defeats part of the original problem. You need to find the largest contiguous *sub-array* in the original input array, and add the values of that sub-array together.

Comment: Ahh.. you are right i thought it to be efficient approach but then the entire array is contiguous sadly correct as u said my bad. So u r saying i should have maintained two pointers one for the initial start and end of contiguous at each portion of the array while traversing the original input array

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: Hmm usually such problems in the way they are written are harder to interpret so as to what they want as output. In this case my bad as i am rookie to programming certainly made a blunder in understanding it. Thanks @Dave Newton

Comment: Agreed; understanding what the problem actually *is* is often the hardest part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistook contiguous subarray problem to a subset problem instead cause you shouldn't be using sorting in the logic. You could refer the question here which handles negative numbers as well. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

Comment: Thanks for the help yes i misunderstood it completely i agree my bad

Comment: no problem buddy glad to help, could you close this answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent explanation of the Maximum Subarray Problem on [this page of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).  Essentially, you are looking for an implementation of Kadane's algorithm, which is explained in the article.